# Initialization a custom class with iVar causing memory leak - iOS

Tags: ios, objective-c, memory-management, memory-leaks

I have a class called `RequestController` which is responsible for downloading, parsing the data and puts them on a strong property array which is accessible from the parent.

The issue here is that the method which initialising the `RequestController` is executed more than once and using Allocations I noticed that it occurring a memory leak and objects are never released. The RequestController variable is an iVar. Also the RequestController has a delegate back to parent controller.

**RequestController.h**

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>

//================

@protocol RequestControllerDelegate <NSObject>

@required
- (void)RequestControllerRequestSuccessful:(NSInteger)mode;
- (void)RequestControllerRequestFailedWithError:(NSInteger)code;

@end

//=================

@interface RequestController : NSObject <NSURLSessionDataDelegate>

@property (nonatomic, assign) id <RequestControllerDelegate> delegate;

@property(nonatomic,strong)NSMutableArray *resultArray;
@property(nonatomic,strong)NSMutableArray *purposesArray;

-(instancetype)initAndRegisterUserWithTelephone:(NSString*)tel Delegate:(id<RequestControllerDelegate>)del;
-(void)nulifyArrays;

@end
```

Initialising the object in **RequestController.m**

```
@implementation RequestController{

        NSURLSession *conn;
        NSArray *responseArray;
        NSMutableData *responseData;
        NSString *reqEmail;

}
@synthesize delegate,resultArray;

#pragma mark - Init Functions
-(instancetype)initAndRegisterUserWithTelephone:(NSString*)tel Delegate:(id<RequestControllerDelegate>)del{



    self = [super init];

    if (self) {

        currentMode=RQRegisterMode;

        self.delegate=del;

        //Check for internet connection
        bool internet = [self internetConnectivity];

        //Sending the requests on the server
        if(internet){

            NSString* url = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@/someurlwithparams",API_URL];

            NSMutableURLRequest *request = [NSMutableURLRequest requestWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:url] cachePolicy:NSURLRequestUseProtocolCachePolicy timeoutInterval:10];

            NSString *param= [NSString stringWithFormat:@"method=%@",tel];

            NSData *requestBodyData = [param dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];

            request.HTTPBody = requestBodyData;

            // Specify that it will be a POST request
            request.HTTPMethod = @"POST";


            NSURLSessionConfiguration *sessionConfig =[NSURLSessionConfiguration defaultSessionConfiguration];
            conn = [NSURLSession sessionWithConfiguration:sessionConfig delegate:self delegateQueue:[NSOperationQueue mainQueue]];

            NSURLSessionDataTask *dataTask= [conn dataTaskWithRequest:request];
            [dataTask resume];
        }

        else
        {

            //No internet connection
            [delegate RequestControllerRequestFailedWithError:RCNoInternetError];

        }



    }
    return self;

}
```

In the parent controller I initialise the object as:

```
req = [[RequestController alloc]initAndRegisterUserWithTelephone:fullTel Delegate:self];
```

And I have these delegates:

```
-(void)RequestControllerRequestSuccessful:(NSInteger)mode{
    [SVProgressHUD dismiss];
    [self manageError:NoError];
   //Copying the data to local variable
  self.array = [NSMutableArray alloc]initWithArray:[req resultArray]];

}

-(void)RequestControllerRequestFailedWithError:(NSInteger)code{
    [SVProgressHUD dismiss];
    [self manageError:code];

}
```

So far so good but as soon as I reinitialise the RequestController I have a memory leak.
What I am doing wrong here?

**Update 1**
This line is causing the leak:

```
conn = [NSURLSession sessionWithConfiguration:sessionConfig delegate:self delegateQueue:[NSOperationQueue mainQueue]];
```

**Update 2**

Replacing `self` with `nil` is solving the problem BUT I need the delegates of **NSURLSession**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue was that I didn't invalidated the NSURLSession as soon as I finished the task.

By Apple:

> Once invalidated, references to the delegate and callback objects are
>   broken. After invalidation, session objects cannot be reused.

So I used `[conn invalidateAndCancel]` after finishing my task in my delegates and the leak is gone.

Answer (score -1):

Try using: [AFNetWorking](https://github.com/afnetworking/afnetworking)

> AFNetworking is a delightful networking library for iOS and Mac OS X.

and [Singleton](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/General/Conceptual/DevPedia-CocoaCore/Singleton.html), I think is the best way to handle a request to the server.

this in RequestManager.h:

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h> 

@interface RequestManager : NSObject

    + (RequestManager *)sharedClass;

    - (void)registerUserWithTelephone:(NSString *)tel
                              success:(void(^)(BOOL finished, NSArray *JSONResponse))success;
```

this in RequestManager.m:

```
#import "RequestManager.h"
#import "AFNetworking.h"

@implementation RequestManager

static RequestManager *sharedClassInstance = nil;

+ (RequestManager *) sharedClass {
        @synchronized(self) {
            if (!sharedClassInstance)
                sharedClassInstance = [[RequestManager alloc] init];
            return sharedClassInstance;
        }
 }

- (void)registerUserWithTelephone:(NSString *)tel
                          success:(void(^)(BOOL finished, NSArray *JSONResponse))success{

AFHTTPRequestOperationManager *manager = [AFHTTPRequestOperationManager manager];

manager.responseSerializer = [AFHTTPResponseSerializer serializer];
manager.requestSerializer = [AFHTTPRequestSerializer serializer];

NSString *URLString = @"URL STRING";

NSDictionary *parameters = @{@"PARAMETER NAME" : tel};

[manager POST:URLString parameters:parameters success:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, id responseObject) {

    NSError *error = nil;
    NSArray *data = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:responseObject
                                                    options:0
                                                      error:&error];
    success(YES, data);


} failure:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, NSError *error) {

    NSData *errorData = error.userInfo[AFNetworkingOperationFailingURLResponseDataErrorKey];
    NSDictionary *serializedData = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:errorData options:kNilOptions error:nil];

    NSLog(@"RequestManager error code %ld",[operation.response statusCode]);

}];

}
```

You can get it in a controller like this:

```
#import "RequestManager.h"

[[RequestManager sharedClass] registerUserWithTelephone:telNumberString
                              success:^(BOOL finished, NSDictionary *JSONResponse){

NSLog(@"%@", JSONResponse);

}];
```

This is the kind of code that I use in my app.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I know about AFNetworking but my question was about solving an issue with memory leak.